# When I am trying to give concatenated string to the image require function it throws me a error in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image: java]

```
<ActivityBadgesComponent
                      badgeImage={
                        item.completed
                          ? require('../images/ic_' + item.game_level.toLowerCase() + '_active.png')
                          : require(`../images/ic_${item.game_level.toLowerCase()}_inactive.png`)
                      }
                    />
```

P.S -> I have also tried giving the values withing string.

```
require(`../images/ic_${item.game_level.toLowerCase()}_active.png`)
```

This also didn't work.

In my require function I am trying to give some dynamic string to the image depending on the value but it can't load. When I give some static values then it works perfectly.

`ActivityBadgesComponent.js`

```
  <Image
            source={this.props.badgeImage}/>
```

Comment: Nop, it did not help.

Comment: This is the same issue, React Native does not allow dynamic strings in a require call. You need to use one of the alternatives mentioned in the duplicate post.